# How to make a post method with data class + retrofit + moshi in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, android-jetpack-compose, moshi

I want to fill the data class with the data received from the user and pass it to the service with retrofit. The structure I set up is the mvvm structure and how can I adapt it to this structure,

The structure I have set up is as follows.

[image]

**hear is my Data model code**

**RegisterLoginDataModel**

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class RegisterLoginDataModel(

    @Json(name = "userGender")
    var userGender: String?,

    @Json(name = "userGoal")
    var userGoal: String?,

    @Json(name = "userTargetWeight")
    var userTargetWeight: String?,

    @Json(name = "userCurrentWeight")
    var userCurrentWeight: String?,

    @Json(name = "userTargetHeight")
    var userTargetHeight: String?,

    @Json(name = "userCurrentHeight")
    var userCurrentHeight: String?,

    @Json(name = "userBirthDay")
    var userBirthDay: String?,

    @Json(name = "userMail")
    var userMail: String?,

    @Json(name = "userName")
    var userName: String?,

    @Json(name = "userPassword")
    var userPassword: String?
)
```

I have a data class that I will use for post in the data package. Can I access it directly from the ui or do I need to create a separate class for the domain and ui package, how can I do this? Could you help ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of architecture, it is better to build a model in the domain layer
which ends with Request.

Then give it to your network layer library ( in here retrofit ).

The operation of creating an instance of the model you created in the domain layer is also done in a place like UseCase